# How to make left join in many to many relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, left-join

I am new in laravel. I have 3 tables
users
ingredients
user_ingredients(pivot table)

Now i have established many-to-many relationship but I have a special requirement that I want to get matching records(which is done) with all the ingredients in ingredients table. I can do it using query_builder or raw but I want to do it in eloquent.

I have searched about 4 hours to find any solution in eloquent but did not found.

Here is my code

User Model

```
public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient', 'user_ingredients');
    }
```

Ingredient Model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_ingredients');
    }
```

Controller Code

```
$ingredients  = $user->ingredients()->get();
```

Query Builder query

```
select ingredients.*,user_ingredients.liked from ingredients LEFT JOIN user_ingredients  on ingredients.id = user_ingredients.ingredient_id and user_ingredients.user_id=129
```

I have checked has(),with() but nothing according to my requirement.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Please paste the raw query example raw example you mention, for better understanding.

Comment: so you want ingredients of a particular user??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes, but with that particular ingredients i need all ingredients in the ingredients table.

Comment: using relationship you will get the related rows only.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Do you have any solution of my requirement?

Comment: @SeverinDK select ingredients.*,user_ingredients.liked from ingredients LEFT JOIN user_ingredients  on ingredients.id = user_ingredients.ingredient_id and user_ingredients.user_id=129

Comment: @dev you can fetch all rows from ingredients table and then match them with user ingredients.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon please comment if you have solid answer with code example.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure about your question. You want to get all the ingredients from a user? You should be able to just do `$user->ingredients` Access it as a property. It's Laravel magic.

Comment: @SeverinDK What is confusing in this? It is simple left join. I repeat again. Simple left join of  ingredients and user table. I have also paste the simple raw sql query.

If for example my statement is not clear then query is simple left join is query also confusing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are just trying to access all the ingredients on the user model? In that case, you should be able to just do `$user->ingredients`

You can access the relationship as a property on the user object. It's some behind the scenes Laravel magic that handles this.

Comment: I want to get ingredients of user and all the ingredients in the ingredients table. It is simple left join issue. I am not sure why you are still confuse.

Comment: Laravel's orm joins are an anti pattern. Try to describe your problem more generic as you already tell us how to solve it with a join

Comment: @mrhn I have already described problem with a raw sql query. Do me one favor and convert that raw query in laravel eloquent.

Comment: And why do you think this question has gone cold? You are able to do all with basic laravel relations but you want a join.